# Am I thinking about MVC correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I'm writing an application that details an applicant's status in our company through Salesforce; when one of our employees enters their Enquiry ID, it shows their status (cleared, not cleared) and, if not cleared, what the applicant needs to fix before they can proceed in their program.

I want to make sure that I am thinking about my application's different areas correctly. Here is what I have:

- **Model**: The applicant class has a dynamic function, such as `Application.find_by_Enquiry_Token__c_and_Account_dot_LastName_from_Opportunity`, and when requested it returns the information from Salesforce
- **Controller**: Parses the returned data from Salesforce and creates hashes with the information, such as `@applicant[:general_information] = {:first_name = data[:Account].first[:FirstName], :last_name = data[:Account].first[:LastName]}`.
- **View**: Displays the information generated by the controller. However, it has it's own logic and checks, such as changing the color of a `div` depending on if they are clear (`class="success"`), if they are not clear (`class="danger"`) or if they have some conditional information (`class="warning"`).

I think I have this correct, except I'm a little worried about my view because I have a bit of Ruby code in there to perform checks based on the returned data, mainly to colorize but also to show certain errors. Is this okay/does this follow standards? Or should I try to refactor my application and push this up to the controller?

Comment: You are using Rails. Why the hell would you care about MVC ?!

Answer (score 0):

I would say having some ruby code like you do in the view is fine as long as you aren't performing long queries or setting instance variables in the view. Also another sign to start moving code from the view to the controller is if you feel the view is getting cluttered and hard to understand. From what you said, this seems like it is not a problem though.

One thing I would recommend changing is to make the method name on the model shorter. Shorter method names are much easier to understand and as you have it, the method name is very long and unwieldy. Other than that, I think you are doing everything well!

Comment: Ah, the method name is dynamic. It works similarly to `Rails`'s `find_by` method on SQL databases.

Answer (score 0):

Displaying the correct classes in the view is fine and can't really be done anywhere else. If you feel like your views are getting messy, consider dividing them into partials or using [Haml](http://haml.info/) for views instead of ERB.

Answer (score 0):

Model is where your application's business logic goes, including parsing data, and everything related to your domain.

Controllers handle interactions with the user. So, basically, in a webapp if a user goes to a URL what should your application do. This should not be doing anything other than handing off tasks to other classes and then rendering a view.

Views are just that. They should be super simple and straightforward as possible. You can extract logic from views into helpers or even presenters/decorators. Views handle what gets displayed to a user.

In your app I would have:
SalesforceApiGateway class which handles communications with Salesforce, I wouldn't be surprised if there was already a gem out there to handle this.

A model class for each Salesforce resource you are accessing. These would setup the proper call to the API gateway to pull the right data for the given resource.
This could get hairy quickly and may need to be extracted further: 1 class for interfacing with the gateway and a model class the resources as you would want to access them from your application.

Your controller should not be parsing any Salesforce data, but rather taking a user request and and wiring that up to the proper model.

The biggest thing to keep in mind is your classes should be doing one thing and one thing only. If you can't talk about your class without saying "and" then it is probably doing too much.
So you have a class that interfaces with the API. You have a class that parses the API. You have a class that brings an api's resource into your domain, etc.

Comment: So a lot of my processing should be moved up to various models?

Comment: And if the problem being solved doesn't really reside within your domain, then it should be in lib. You should think in lib as stuff that could easily be extracted into a gem